# .Net Core IdentityServer using custom table for ApplicationUser

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, token, identityserver4

We are implementing identityserver authentication for our .net core api project. I have implemented identityserver infrastructure which created AspNetUsers,AspNetUserRoles etc. tables. The users are inserted in aspnetusers table. I want to use our member table instead of aspnetusers table. How can I do that?

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            [Required]
            [MaxLength(200)]
            public String Name { get; set; }
        }



    [HttpPost]
            [Route("token")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> CreateToken([FromBody] LoginModel loginModel)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var loginResult = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginModel.Username, loginModel.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                    if (!loginResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return BadRequest();
                    }

                    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginModel.Username);

Login();

                    return Ok(GetToken(user));
                }
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            }
```

Comment: When you use the Identity tables you should extend ApplicationUser (AspNetUsers table). Why would you want to hold on to the member table?

Comment: We already have a structure and records in that table.

Comment: Are there other dependencies on that table? Otherwise migrating would be easier.

Comment: If this is the only way, we could do this. But isn't there a way to use that table?

Comment: When you are using the Identity tables then I would use it as is. It is extensible so you have options. But you don't have to use the Idenity Tables. These are not part of IdentityServer and can be replaced with a custom user store.

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll consider extending table.

Comment: Yup, as others have said you can extend ASP.Net Identity storage but it still depends on the user entity inheriting from IdentityUser<TKey>. You could map the entity to a different table name via the EF ModelBuilder but it'd still have to contain the columns within the IdentityUser base class.

Comment: As an aside - what is the above code sample doing? It looks like you've created a custom endpoint to issue a token rather than using the ResourceOwnerPassword grant type via the token endpoint. Do you actually have IdentityServer4 in play at all or are you just using ASP.Net Identity and manually creating tokens?

Comment: This is the way I create token and authenticate. actually here is the piece of code for authenticate; var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };

            var identity = new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(user.UserName);
            identity.AddClaims(claims);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, new string[0]);
            HttpContext.User = principal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;